# Where can I get the Invitation letter for Romania for C/TU(tourism) visa?

Tags: romania, invitation-letters, tourism

Can someone help me where can I get the Invitation letter for Romania for C/TU(tourism) visa?

I'm from India and planning to visit in about 4-5 weeks. I will take care of all my expenses, itinerary, stay and flight.

[The official site](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2046?page=3) does mention about the invitation on the page 3.

---

I will take care of all my expenses, itinerary, stay and flight. It does mention about the invitation on the page 3. https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2046?page=3.

Comment: Where are you staying and why and how are you travelling? A hotel or travel company may be able to provide something; or if you're visiting/staying with someone or there on business see if they can provide a letter. (I'm not specifically familiar with Romania).

Comment: [Official site](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2046) does **not** list an invitation as a requirement for C/TU visa. You only need confirm accommodation booking, itinerary (inc tickets), medical insurance and proof of funds.

Comment: Based on OP's information & from [official guidance](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2051) it appears Indian nationals **do** need an invitation previously approved by the General Inspectorate for Immigration.

Comment: (+1) Good question, the documentation is not very clear about that. Based on the form, it seems you should get it from whoever will provide accomodation (family member if you are staying with them, hotel if you booked a hotel, etc.) but I am not sure. A Google search also easily reveal travel agencies offering invitations for a fee but I cannot vouch for them.